# Change x-axis limits for partykit::lmtree (mob) plots

Tags: r, party

Just like in title: I'd like to change x-axis limits for `partykit::lmtree` (`mob`) plots.

**Toy example**

Let shape of `Y~X+X^2` regression depend on `A`:

```
A <- rep(1:5, each=4)
X <- 1:20
Y <- X*A+(A<3)*X^2+rnorm(20, mean=10)
```

Now build `lmtree` with polynomial term and plot:

```
library(partykit)
mytree <- lmtree(Y~poly(X,2,raw=T) | A, minsize=3)
plot(mytree)
```

To get this:
[image]

Limits of X-axis are clearly based on range of `poly(X,2,raw=T)` not on range of `X`. How can I change them?

**What I have tried**

- Use `tp_args=list(xlim=c(1,20))`. This failed because (I think) there is no `xlim` parameter in `node_bivplot()` that controls plots.
- Find some other parameter of `node_bivplot()` that controls axes. I can't see any.
- Use `Y~X+I(X^2)` inside `lmtree`. This produces separate plots for `X` and `I(X^2)` on each leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `xscale` and `yscale` arguments (grid graphics equivalents to the base graphics arguments `xlim` and `ylim`) are set internally in `node_bivplot()` and cannot be modified through arguments.

In your case I would recommend to set up the two regressors from the polynomial manually (`X + I(X^2)`) and then only create a terminal panel for the first of these two regressors (`which = 1`):

```
mytree <- lmtree(Y ~ X + I(X^2) | A, minsize = 3)
plot(mytree, tp_args = list(which = 1))
```

[image: mytree]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although, I think it would be useful to allow for `xscale` and `yscale` change. Numbers that are plotted on graphs are not very pretty. I'm sometimes asked "Why you chose such strange numbers to show on plot?" and then I have to reply that it was not me who chose them ;). For all my base plots I use `xlim=range(pretty(X))` and I find it working very well.